# Pylint does not recognise PYTHONPATH in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong(i.e. stupid), but running

```py
from stuff.modules import maths
```

Pylint just keeps giving

```py
No name 'modules' in module 'stuff' pylint(no-name-in-module)
Unable to import 'stuff.modules' pylint(import-error)
```

My `stuff`-module is located at `/home/abb`, so I tried to add both `PYTHONPATH="/home/abb"` and `PYTHONPATH="/home/abb/stuff"` to an `.env`-file, but since it still gives the errors, I think the problem is that **I'm also using the `stuff`-folder as my workspace**.

I don't think it's a problem with the `.env`-file, since I'm also importing from my `lib`-module located in the same folder as `stuff`, and this doesn't raise any errors.

(Oh, and if it is important, I'm running this on an SSH-connection)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I did 'fix' it by faking another path by using `ProjectRootFolder.stuff.modules`, saving, and typing again `stuff.modules`.

I know that it was not a real fix, but from then it worked, also it is stands ever marked with a red under-line.

I explained my issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65182339/same-import-different-errors).

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit python.analysis.extraPaths.

I tried the .env route and could not get it to work.  I actually spent a couple hours on it.

If you go file->preferences->settings or ctrl+, you can search for "extrapath".

Just add your /home/abb/stuff there and it should work.