# Same import, different errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-import

I am making tests for my code, but I'm facing a strange import error.

Notes:

- I am using VSCode version: 1.46.1
- PYTHONPATH is set to project's root

Folder structure is this:

```
-app.py
-models
---language.py
---category.py
-my_tests
---unit
------models
---------category_test.py
---------language_test.py
```

In category_test, I do import "Category" class by using:

```
from models.category import Category
```

In language_test, I do import "Language" class by using:

```
from models.language import Language
```

In category_test case, all works fine.
In language_test case, I encounter one "Import error".
Instead of searching at the project's root as it does for category_test file, it searches on my_test/unit/models folder.
[image]

When i print sys.path, result is as expected:

```
[
 '/home/ste3/Documents/Projects/SteFunBot/my_tests/unit/models', -> current folder
 '/home/ste3/Documents/Projects/SteFunBot', -> PYTHONPATH
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', 
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', 
 '/home/ste3/Documents/Projects/SteFunBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages'
]
```

How can I fix this?

***EDIT***
I think it is a linter issue. Can it be?
If I try to import the moudules by specifying the path from root (*step1*) and then I recover the import removing the root from the import path (*step2*),  it works:
**Step 1**

```
from SteFunBot.models.language import Language
```

**Step 2**

```
from models.language import Language
```

Comment: The module is named `language.py`, but the import is `from models.languages`.  Those two names are not the same.

Comment: Yeah, but also modifying as "language" it does not work. The point is that python is suggesting me to use "language_test" module instead of "language". I did make a mistake writing this post.

Comment: Please include text as text, not screenshots. [This is what your question looks like with a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6htQ.png)

Comment: Can you try to add an `__init__.py` to the root/models folder?

Comment: I did it already, in order to gain the opportunity to add it to the import path. The issue is anyway present.

Answer (score 0):

When importing modules (files) in other folders, VSCode starts from the parent folder of the file by default. Therefore, we can help VSCode find the module path in the following ways:

1. Use absolute paths. The way to set the VSCode search path is to start from the current project. VSCode first changes to the project folder path before executing the code.

   For example: Use

   > ```
   > "env": {
   >                 "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}",
   >             }
   > ```

   in "`launch.json`" to add the absolute path of the project:

   [image]
2. Use relative paths. Find the project path based on the relative path of the file (using the imported module file), then VSCode will start searching from the project folder.

   For example: Use the following code at the beginning of the file to find the project folder path:

   [image]

Comment: PYTHONPATH environment variable is already set, as you can see from the printout of sys.path, so that is not the problem. My point is that VSCode linter is not getting that pythonpath is actually set I think.

Comment: After you set "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "D:\\...\\folder"} in the "launch.json" file, does it still not work?

Comment: It works after I do the trick I did write after the edit. Otherwise it does not. I think that the point is not the environment variable: I did set it manually on O.S.